# Character enlarges when I use "Import as Planes" and when character moving front

Tags: animation

I created a video where a character is walking on a street. I used green screen and removed the background. I used *Import as Planes* and brought the images to my scene.

Now when I place the images (seq of images) on my scene, the character enlarges as it walks forward. I have done few animations where character is not moving or moving in sideways. There is no issue there. But for the scene where the character is moving front or back, the size of the character changes.

Is there any technique I can use? Or I have to adjust the frame's height frame by frame to fit to my scene.